# C++ debugging: Terminated with SIGABRT

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, sigabrt

I am trying to write a program, in C++, which runs on a cluster of machines, and all machines are talking to each other over TCP sockets. Program crashes randomly at one of the machines. I did an analysis of core-dump with gdb. Following are the output:

```
$ gdb executable dump

  Core was generated by `/home/user/experiments/files/executable 2 /home/user/'.
  Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
  0 0x00007fb76a084c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
  56    ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

  (gdb) backtrace
  0 0x00007fb76a084c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
  1 0x00007fb76a088028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
  2 0x00007fb76a0c12a4 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fb76a1cd113 "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
  3 0x00007fb76a158bbc in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=<optimized out>, msg@entry=0x7fb76a1cd0aa "buffer overflow detected") at fortify_fail.c:38
  4 0x00007fb76a157a90 in __GI___chk_fail () at chk_fail.c:28
  5 0x00007fb76a158b07 in __fdelt_chk (d=<optimized out>) at fdelt_chk.c:25
  6 0x000000000040a918 in LocalSenderPort::run() ()
  7 0x000000000040ae70 in LocalSenderPort::LocalSenderPort(unsigned int, std::string, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, char*) ()
  8 0x00000000004033d5 in main ()
```

Any suggestions for what should I look? How should I proceed? Any help is really appreciated.

I am not sharing code right now, as its a large code spread across files. But I can share if needed.

Comment: Assuming that you're using G++/Clang pass the `-g` option to the compiler. That will generate debug symbol information and should allow you to see the lines of code where the crash was caused from in gdb.

Comment: @tambre I have added -g during compilation. And it does shows  following : #0 0x00007fb76a084c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56

Comment: Don't even try to post the stack trace in a comment. Instead edit the new (and useful) the stack trace into the question. Though the stack trace indicating the location in your own code should usually be enough for you to debug the rest yourself.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The raise entry is not interesting. LocalSenderPort::run entry is. It should show the line number idf compiled with -g.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have already posted the debuggers output. As I said the code is large and spread across files. Hence I am not posting it but can post if required. And I am not asking solutions, I was asking for suggestion to how to proceed.

Comment: @tambre. Sorry for the confusion. Those #s appeared as they appeared in terminal output. The function run is an infinite while loop after initial setup it keeps executing.

Answer (score 4):

This error: `__fdelt_chk (d=<optimized out>) at fdelt_chk.c:25` means that your program violated precondition of one of the `FD_*` macros.

The source of [fdelt_chk](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=debug/fdelt_chk.c;h=7fe243d2174211257976ca95091b507c2a9499bd;hb=HEAD) is quite simple, and there are only two conditions under which it fails: you pass in negative file descriptor, or you pass in a file descriptor greater than 1023.

In this day and age, using `select` and/or `FD_SET` in any program that can have more than 1024 simultaneous connections (which Linux easily allows) can only end in tears. Use [epoll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was something on same lines. But it's not with select. function socket is returning -1 when it has already returned 1023 sockets. And all of them are alive yet. How can I increase the permissible number of total alive sockets at a time?

Comment: If `socket` returns error, it's likely because you are running into the limit on total number of file descriptors (`man setrlimit` or `man ulimit`). **Note:** if you increase that limit *and* are using `select` or `FD_*` macros, then you'll immediately run into the problem in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's correct, now I am in the problem mentioned in your answer. Will go with epoll now.

Comment: This answer is still one of the top results on google, and you have saved me a pile of work with this summary. I bumped the problem code from select to epoll and everything was resolved. Many thanks!